# object is no longer moving smoothly

Tags: 3d-view, edit-mode

I do not know what I did to make it do this, if anything. After creating an eye. I went back to my other object to palce it inside of it. Resized eye. But now when I try to move it into place it moves in chuncks. Like it can only move by one of them "block sizes" in the graph that shows in the vewier. No longer able to move in minutiae movements.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Is that little magnet icon on your tool bar near the bottom (default area) selected? If yes then make sure it is not selected. It's that simple.

Comment: Glad you found your own answer. For future reference, you can override snapping if it is active by holding the Ctrl key.

Comment: someone gave me a minus 2 for figuring it out myself wow... that is at least 3 hours in therapy.. :( hehe

Comment: @uxserx-bw  Answering your own question is by no means discouraged on StackExchange, in fact it is encouraged.  But self-answers are still held to the quality standard any other answer is.  Please improve this answer explaining it in a little more detail, a screenshot would help too.